# Change the name of the top left "cell" in an R tibble

Tags: r

I'm looking for help with changing a value in  an R tibble. When I try to make a tibble with the following code, I cannot get it to say "Row number" in cell A1. Right now A1 is blank (see my code below) I would appreciate any tips, thank you!

| Row number | minutes | margin_of_error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 53 | 3 |
| 2 | 75 | 0 |
| 3 | 44 | 0 |
| 4 | 43 | 0 |
| 5 | 58 | 0 |
| 6 | 13 | 5 |

```
minutes <- c(53,75,44,43,58,13)
margin_of_error <- c(3,0,0,0,0,5)
new_tibble <- tibble(minutes,margin_of_error)
```

Comment: It's a property of the tibbles that the row numbers are displayed on the left when printed. This is not an actual column of the tibble. Compared to Excel, it's the equivalent of the grey margins with the row numbers (what is left of A1). So in a normal tibble, column A is `minutes`, and column `B` is `margin_of_error`. If you want row numbers to be their own column, you can make it so as shown by Matthew and the linked question, but there will still be additional row numbers in the margin that are not an actual part of the tibble.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
MINUTES <- c(53,75,44,43,58,13)

`MARGIN OF ERROR` <- c(3,0,0,0,0,5)

new_tibble <- tibble(MINUTES,`MARGIN OF ERROR`)

new_tibble$`ROW NUMBER` <- rownames(new_tibble)

new_tibble <- new_tibble[,c(3,1,2)]

print.data.frame(new_tibble,row.names = FALSE)

 ROW NUMBER MINUTES MARGIN OF ERROR
          1      53               3
          2      75               0
          3      44               0
          4      43               0
          5      58               0
          6      13               5
```

Comment: Thanks, it isn't exactly what I'm looking for because the row number column (1-6) are duplicated with that solution. I want the row name column to say "row number" in cell A1. Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: `tibble` has a convenience function for this that automatically places the row names into first position as an explicit variable - `new_tibble %>% rownames_to_column("ROW NUMBER")`.